# Navigate to a specific route in MAUI using Shell, from OnNewIntent in MainActivity?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, maui

I decided to experiment with MAUI. I am approaching first an Android App, and using Shell for navigation.

My App has 2 ways of opening:

1. When it's opened by the user tapping on the icon
2. Through a deep link, triggered by another app.

The issue I'm having is that when the app is triggered through the Deep link, I need to navigate to a specific page. I am trying to do it on the OnNewIntent accessing the Current instance of Shell, but when doing `GoToAsync("my_route")` it gives an error when trying to navigate to the new page.

This is what I have on my MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    var action = intent.Action;
    var data = intent.DataString;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) && data.Contains("/data/")) {
                       
        if(Shell.Current != null) 
        {                    
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myroute)";
            // Also tried: 
            // - Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myroute").Wait();
            // - App.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//myroute")); (suggested by @toolmakersteve )
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'No view found for id 0x1
> (unknown) for fragment ShellItemRenderer{19d353d}
> (6c8560ab-dd58-4cbf-9e8b-2b9e12315f45 id=0x1)'

I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that what I'm  doing is not possible, so I need to find the RIGHT way to navigate to a specific page from `OnNewIntent` on MAUI, using Shell navigation.

**UPDATE:** It's also important to note that when the Deep Link triggers the app to open, there are two different behaviours:

1. If the app was already running, it throws the above mentioned exception
2. If the app was not already running, it opens regularly on the main screen, with no errors, but I would expect it to navigate to the desired Page.

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you override method `OnNewIntent` in `MainActivity`? If it is convinient for you ,could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: I solved this by saving in Preferences the route from deep linking and then removing it every other start up. But it's very cumbersome. Did you find a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that `GoToAsync("myroute")` works if you use it somewhere more typical, such as a button press.

Assuming that works, then perhaps the intent code isn't running in the Dispatcher context (previously known as MainThread). Try:

```cs
Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => {
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myroute");
});
```

---

**VERSION 2**

Perhaps deep link logic runs BEFORE App's OnResume.
If so, this might work:

In App.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    ...
    public static bool FromDeepLink;

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        if (FromDeepLink)
        {
            FromDeepLink = false;
            MainPage = new MainPage();
            Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
            {
                Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myroute");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then in OnNewIntent:

```cs
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) && data.Contains("/data/")) {
    App.FromDeepLink = true;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your quick reply. I have tried this and still gives the same error. Also made sure my route works from within the app, and it does.

An interesting to notice too, is that, IF the app was not previously running, and is triggered by the DeepLink, it opens as it normally would, not navigating to the route I want to.
I'll update that behaviour on the question.

Comment: Added Version 2. I haven't used deep links, so this is speculation.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this doesn't work either. Looks like OnResume is not triggered when the the app is resumed through my intent.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually @ToolmakerSteve answer is correct, but the OnResume event of the Application class seems not to fire when the app is resumed by intent (seems to be a Maui bug), however Android's native OnResume works and fires correctly even when the app is resumed via intent, all you have to do is in the MainActivity class to override Android's native OnResume method:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();

    var fromDeepLink = Preferences.Get("FromDeepLink", false);
    if (fromDeepLink)
    {
        Preferences.Set("FromDeepLink", false);
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myroute");
    }
}

protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);

    var action = intent.Action;
    var data = intent.DataString;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) && data.Contains("/data/"))
    {
        Preferences.Set("FromDeepLink", true);
    }
}
```